# Python: Quitting the loop depends of number of values

Tags: python, loops

Im using bitbucket API to get some data. This API is presented like:

```
values:
    0:
        Other keys
    1:
        Other keys
```

Maximum values per page is in range 0-24. So I can get data in normall loop. But how can I stop getting data, when number of values is different than 24 and without checking it?

I was trying something like that:

```
r = requests.get(url).json()
for i in range(0,24)
    if r['values'][i+1]:
        data.append(r['values'][i])
    else:
        break
```

But this solution doesnt work and show out of range error

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in r['values']:
   data.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to get values from 0 to 24, simply only have your if statement to be

```
if r['values'][i]:
   data.append(r['values'][i])
```

the reason you get the out of range is because when i is equal to 24, it can't find 25 because it doesn't exists.

Comment: I think I didn't write it correct. Maximum values per page is 24, but it can be also 10,17,22 and Im looking for the way to get all of them without checking it on website

Comment: I don’t think that’s the issue. You always count from 0-24, but if there are less than 24 items, you request items which are out of range. You need a while loop, with an if statement as break -> so if I>23 -> break the loop.